# Which EventLog corresponds to the WHEA-BERT (Windows Hardware Error Architecture - Boot Error Report Table) entries?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-error-reporting

The WHEA (Windows Hardware Error Architecture) defines the table-based error reporting mecahnism by which firmware can reports hardware errors to operating system. There are 4 tables involved:

- BERT: Boot Error Report Table ◄ This is to record last boot error to OS
- HEST: Hardware Error Srouce Table ◄ This is to record runtime error to OS
- EINJ: Error Injection Table
- ERST: Error Record Serialization Table

I simulated corrected memory errors when Windows Sever 2012 is running. And I can see entries appear in the below event logs. These event logs basically reflect the HEST.

[image: HEST EventLog examples]

Now I simulated some last boot errors in the BERT, but I don't know which event log is correspondent to BERT.

I searched a bit but no luck. Does anyone know which EventLog the BERT errors are written to?